# “terminal is not fully functional” over ssh in a *shell* buffer

Tags: tramp, shell

I'm using the shell (`M-x shell`) to connect to a remote host via SSH. After launching some command line tools (mostly **psql**, the postgresql command line interface, but **man** would be the same for example), the shell is giving me the following warning:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional                                                    
-  (press RETURN)
```

As far as I know, this looks like a pager problem. Changing the pager to `cat` in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setenv "PAGER" "/bin/cat")
```

helped me get rid of those messages, but only for local commands (and I do not mind using cat as a pager). As I only have one local instance of Emacs, is there a way to use a different pager on the remote host? Or any other way to get rid of the warning messages, if possible without switching to `ansi-term`? If it's of any help, I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: Alternatively, use `M-x ansi-term` to run a fully-functional terminal, rather than using `M-x shell`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "problem" is that with `M-x shell` (or `M-x eshell` btw), Emacs uses a *very* limited terminal emulator, so that `TERM` is correctly set to `dumb`

Fancy pagers cannot operate under such limited constraints, which is why you have to use `cat` instead.
Now, when you open an ssh connection from that shell, `TERM` is still dumb, but `PAGER` is reset to whatever the other system thinks you should use. In order to fix this, you need to alter your shell configuration on the remote system so that it uses decent defaults whenever it's accessed from a dumb terminal.

Something like:

```
[ "$TERM" = "dumb" ] && export PAGER=/bin/cat
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I'm not supposed to modify the remote server settings, I could either try to send env variables with my ssh connection string... or just get used to ansi-term!

Comment: is there a pager that will display color?

Comment: @erjoalgo For colors, you can use [ccat](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat) instead of cat. The result is really sweet :)